# Android compile , about too many methods

Tags: java, android, compilation

when I compile my android package: It prints

trouble writing output: Too many methods: 65544; max is 65536. By package:
...
...

It's because of I define too many native method in my class. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you have that many methods in the first place?

Comment: I must state the obvious...remove some methods, refactor or move them elsewhere.

Comment: Wtf 65544 methods in 1 package? This is insane. Please refactor your code.

Comment: 1 method a minute and time flies by ...

Comment: break you class into a group of classes

Answer (score -5, accepted):

This clearly indicates that your class is too complicated and shall be refactored in some smaller units.

Comment: Ok. Got it. But is there any other method?

Comment: This isn't one class with that many methods, this is the total number of methods in the entire app.

Comment: You're not alone with this issue.  While refactoring will solve the issue in the near term, there still lies the problem of going over that 64K limit of method signatures.  You'll easily go over this if you find yourself including third part support libraries.  Proguard can help remove some of the unnecessary methods in the support libraries since you don't really want to delve into maintaining a third-party's code base.  I have yet to come across figuring out how to enable debugging with Eclipse builds and have Proguard do that stripping as well.

Answer (score 1):

One solution proposed by Google is using multiple DEX files.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html

From my comment in the other solution by Konstatin, there are cases where you will run over the allotted 64K methods allowed.

Proguard to strip away some of the third party library method calls that you don't use is one temporary solution.